# 2003 Honda CR-V broken part identification

Tags: honda, part-identification, crv

I was wondering if anyone could help me identify what could be a part, or a piece of a part, from my 2003 Honda CR-V. Yesterday, I noticed that the stop lights stayed on after I turned the vehicle off and I found the following pieces on the floor mat:[image]

On the left, I believe, is a shattered 46505-SA5-000 (brake pedal stop pad), but I'm not sure about the piece on the right. For all I know, it could just be debris and not even a part, but I thought I'd ask because if it is a part, then maybe I should take the vehicle to a mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

The white part is definitely the brake switch stop pad. A common failure. The other is not as clear, could be the end of the brake switch plunger rod.

Is it plastic or metal?

Comment: I think it might actually be rubber because it bends easily to a 90 degree angle and then returns to its original shape. I'll try to get some better pictures when I get back from work. Thanks!