# 95 Acura Integra LS: 3rd, left & right brake lights remain on after engine shutdown

Tags: acura, integra, brake-light

### Issue

Brake lights (3rd, left, rear) lights are on after removing keys from ignition.   If not corrected, this will drain the battery

### Corrective Action

- Failed: turn headlights on / off
- Failed: restart vehicle / toggle emergency brake
- disconnected battery to prevent draining the battery

### Question

What can be done to diagnose the root cause of the issue?  Seeking diagnostic procedures and insight.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the brake light switch, then look for the plastic stopper that the switch plunger contacts. If it is missing or broken the switch plunger does not get pushed in causing the lights stay on all the time.  The most likely cause of this sort is failure of the brake switch stopper. An image of a typical broken stopper is seen here.  [broken brake stopper](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/36759/2003-honda-cr-v-broken-part-identification)

The diagram shows hard plastic plug at the top of the moving part of the brake pedal... (#22 in this picture, Acura Part # 46505-SA5-000).. it engages/disengages the plunger to turn on/off the brake lights

[image]

Reference: http://www.team-integra.net/forum/12-generation-two/185192-bad-brake-light-switch.html

Comment: You might want to update your link. Takes us to a previous answer. Better yet, just share the image if you can.

Comment: I had this same issue in my 94 integra.  The plastic stopper was the issue.

Comment: @rpmerf, please comment or edit the solution to explain what was done to correct the problem: was the stopper replaced / repaired etc.  There is no substitute for experience :)

Comment: @gatorback I put a plastic rivet in there (like what holds on the plastic fender covers or interior plastic panels)  It has held for about 6 months now.  Proper fix would be to get the bushing from the Honda dealer.  I should order one now for the next time it breaks.  Another common fix is to tape a penny in place.

Comment: @rpmerf  thank you.  A penny was superglued in place to resolve the issue